# can i charge something via usb when computer is off?

Tags: usb, charging

I have one of those little remote control helicopters and it needs to be charged via USB. It takes 45 minutes to charge.

Can this thing charge when the laptop (macbook pro) is off?
Does it need to be awake/on?
Can it charge if the laptop is asleep/lid closed?